# SOAP UI not working on my machine

Tags: soap, webservice-client, soapui

I tried many version of SOAP UI (3.6.1,3.6,3.5.1) on my machine but after couple of minutes, my screen filled with bubbles.Not sure, if this tool conflicts with anyother tool on my machine. Please let me know, if anybody has some idea.

thanks
Hemish

Comment: Do you have a screen shot or error message?

Comment: You are using SOAP UI and you are getting bubbles on your screen? Really?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you have the "Bubbles" screen saver enabled on your Windows Vista PC and you are inactive for a few minutes causing the screen saver to display.

Without more information that's the best suggestion I can make.